# As the gaven code which uses `std::shared_ptr`, is there any potential problem that i shoud be aware of?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I clearly know the former code below is wrong as it releases the resource twice.But my question is that whether the latter one(check https://godbolt.org/z/ndsHtX) is correct or not.Maybe it's right since the outputs of the terminate.Is there any potential problem that i shoud be aware of? I would be grateful to have some help on this question.

The wrong code:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

using std::shared_ptr;

struct S
{
  shared_ptr<S> dangerous()
  {
     return shared_ptr<S>(this);   // don't do this!
  }

  ~S()
  {
      std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
   shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);
   shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1->dangerous();
   return 0;
}
```

The one i am not sure whether right or wrong:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

using std::shared_ptr;

class S
{
  public: 
    //S() = delete;
    int m_num;

  public:
    static shared_ptr<S> dangerous()
    {
        return make_shared<S>();   // don't do this!
    }

    void setNum(int num)
    {
        m_num = num;
    }


    ~S()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   shared_ptr<S> sp1 = S::dangerous();
   shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1;

   std::cout << sp1.use_count() << std::endl;
   std::cout << sp2.use_count() << std::endl;

   sp1.get()->setNum(99);
   sp1.get()->m_num;

   std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not just use `std::shared_from_this`?

Comment: This code slice is not wroten by myself. It's a part of our project.

Comment: What makes you think the edited code is wrong?

Comment: How is this a question about `shared_from_this` when there is no `shared_from_this` in the code?

Comment: @ interjay  The first example is related to the `shared_from_ths`.It's wrong clearly. Somebody in my term says the code below is to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @Alan Birtles Because what John Zwinck said in his answer.

Comment: But John's answer makes no sense now that you've removed the code he was talking about

Comment: Ok, i reedited, we just talk about the code. I have done some tests, maybe he is right though i don't understand it.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: As the reedited question, i have tested it; the terminate output is not right.You can check it on https://godbolt.org/z/ndsHtX. Though i am a novice in C++, I want to dig deep.

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer, which is not allowed as John Zwinck's answer says.

Comment: @interjay & Alan Birtles I find the problem and correct it.You could check it on https://godbolt.org/z/qTQ5-f. I think this one is right. What do you think of it.One more question, is there any potential problem?

Comment: Now it's just normal use of a `shared_ptr`, and has absolutely nothing to do with `shared_from_this`. You need to explain what you are actually trying to do if you want help in understanding how to do it.

Comment: @interjay Sorry,I have mixed up some terminologys. I am aware of it and reedit the title. I think the latter code slice is wrong because it's with the same problem as the former one.Am i right.

Comment: I'm still not sure what your question is, why do you think the code you've posted is wrong?

Comment: @AlanBirtles  The original code is `return std::shared_ptr<S>();`  it returnes a `null-ptr` and should be replaced by `return make_shared<S>(); `.  Since i have compiled and run the program, I confirm that  `return std::shared_ptr<S>();` returns a `null-ptr`. But i don't fully understand why. If you know, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: If your question is why does `return std::shared_ptr<S>()` return a null pointer put that in your question

Comment: `return std::shared_ptr<S>()` returns a default-constructed instance of `std::shared_ptr<S>`. It's equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<S> ptr; return ptr;` The default constructor sets the object up to hold a null pointer. What else did you expect, and why?